# Spring boot mvc ant mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

[image]

I'm trying to call /admin/addClient,  the rest call is executed, but while returning from the function it adds /admin as prefix hence making call as /admin/admin/addClient instead of /admin/addClient and returns 404. attached logs for more details.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/addClient", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ServiceResponse addClient(@RequestBody AddClientRequest request) {
        LOG.info("Adding Client");
        ServiceResponse response = new ServiceResponse();
        if (request == null || !request.isValid()) {
            response.setCode(ApiResponseUtils.INVALID_REQUEST_CODE);
            response.setMessage(ApiResponseUtils.INVALID_REQUEST_MESSAGE);
            return response;
        }
        try {
            response = adminService.addClient(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error occured while adding client.");
            LOG.error(ApiResponseUtils.EXCEPTION, e);
            response.setCode(ApiResponseUtils.ERROR_CODE);
            response.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }
```

WebSecurityAdapter

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .httpBasic().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/verify").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/setPassword").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/forgotPassword").permitAll()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
         .authenticationEntryPoint(restUnauthorizedEntryPoint)
         .accessDeniedHandler(restAccessDeniedHandler)
         .and()
        .formLogin()
         .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
         .failureHandler(restAuthenticationFailureHandler)
         .successHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
         .usernameParameter("username")
         .passwordParameter("password")
         .permitAll()
         .and()
        .logout()
         .logoutUrl("/logout")
         .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
         .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
         .permitAll()
         .and();
      }
```

Comment: Please don't add screenshots to your posts, simply copy and paste the log output and format it as blockquote.

Comment: Could you please post the rest of the controller class? At least the class header. I have a suspicion...